# Trying to fix outside the bounds of array by avoiding using if, else, if else and switch statements as I can only user if once

Tags: c#

How can I make it so that if the quantityPurchased is greater than or equal to 200 it does not go out of the bounds of array without using an if, if else, else or a switch statement.

```
static double DeterminePercentage(int quantityPurchased)
{
    double[] quantity = { 1, 11, 50, 100, 200 };
    double[] discount = { 0, 7.5, 15, 17.5, 20 };
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < quantity.Length; i++)
    {
        if (quantityPurchased >= quantity[i] && quantityPurchased < quantity[i + 1])
        {
            x = i;
        }
        break;
    }

    return discount[x];
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why can you only use `if` once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop one item less:

```
for (int i = 0; i < quantity.Length - 1; i++) {
```

To have the code work for >200 value you can add another dummy item:

```
double[] quantity = { 1, 11, 50, 100, 200, Int32.MaxValue };
double[] discount = { 0, 7.5, 15, 17.5, 20, 100 };
```

This will have quantity between 200 and Int32.MaxValue have discount of 20%.

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't clarify. If i have it so that it has
for (int i = 0; i < quantity.Length - 1; i++) {
it then ignores the numbers that are 200 or greater which I need to to include. but just if the number is 200 or greater it stops and just matches up with the discount 20%

Answer (score 0):

If your 'quantity' array grows and is still sorted, the optimal and generic answer would be to use a BinarySearch for the value 'quantityPurchased'. It will give you the insertion point ie. point at which the key would be inserted into the array. 
Use this index to return the appropriate value from the discount array.

I don't provide code as i'm not a C# user but implementation should not be very complicated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Add Double.MAX_VALUE to the end of your quantity array:

```
double[] quantity = { 1, 11, 50, 100, 200, Double.MAX_VALUE };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Linq expression.

return discount[discount.IndexOf(quantity.Where(x => x > quantityPurchased).DefaultIfEmpty().Max());